# wp_setup_nav_menu_item() and custom id/classes

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about adding filters.

I'm using add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', '...'); to filter menu items. Is there a way to attach custom id/classes to menu items, so I could style them individually and reference them in Javascript?

Comment: menu items already have unique ids and classes, you can change the defaults by passing arguments to the `wp_nav_menu()`. here's the codex link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add a click handler to a specific menu item. At the moment, I do this by getting the ID with $menu_item->ID and prepending "menu-item-" to it. Then using jQuery's bind() to attach an click event. But this feels very weird to me. And I'm trying to figure out how wp_nav_menu fits in all of this, but I'm not sure it does.

Comment: what i am saying is that you already have your click handlers without the prepending anything. here is the default list element that is  produced by the `wp_nav_menu()`: `<li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-108"></li>`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm making myself clear enough. Or I might just be asking stupid questions since I'm new at wordpress. So how would I go about making this #menu-item-108 to execute my JS function? Just the #menu-item-108 element? And since it depends on the title of the menu item, the user might change the menu and then suddenly, menu-item-109 has to run the function, not menu-item-108. I've already done this, but in such an awkward and messy was I can't believe this is the way it's meant to be done.

Comment: yes, you can use `$('#menu-item-108').click()` for instance. Numbers for each menu item are assigned once a page or taxonomy is added to the menu, and renaming it, or adding new elements don't affect this. And if you remove a menu item, new items will not get the id of the removed item. you can use `wp_nav_menu()` arguments to adjust what will the id and class of menu items be. so you can append the id of taxonomy so both ids, taxonomy and menu, are the same, if you need that